# Proving that the $k$th element of $A \cup B$ is median of (the first $k$ elements of A) $\cup$ (the first $k$ elements of $b$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

By union here, I am referring to a union where duplicates are allowed.

Given two sorted arrays, A and B, how do you prove that the $k$th element in the union of A and B is the median of the following two sets: first $k$ elements of A and first $k$ elements of B? If $k$ is greater than the size of a set then assume that the extra elements are infinities.

For example, take the sets:

A = {1, 3, 5, 6}

B = {2, 4, 5}

$A \cup B$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6}

The 3rd element in $A \cup B$ is 3, which is the median of the sets:

{1, 3, 5}
and {2, 4, 5}

The 4th element is $A \cup B$ is 4, which is the median of

{1, 3, 5, 6} and {2, 4, 5, $\infty$}

How do you prove that this is always true?

Comment: There's nothing like a sorted set. In a set, order of the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: I mean something analogous to an array of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true in general. The median of $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,5\right\}$ is $\frac{3 + 4}{2} = 3.5$.

The reason for this is that if you union $2k$ elements together, then there are an even number of elements in the union. That means the median will always be an average of the two middle most numbers.

**Edit:**

In response to your definition of median. It is clear that there will be $2k$ elements in the union and that they are in order, but then the median must be the smaller of the $k$th and the $(k + 1)$th elements in the set. However, it's in order. Thus it must then be the $k$th element.

By the way, the reason why the median is decided from the middle two numbers if the set has an even number of elements is because the list can be constructed from the middle outward like so

$$a, b $$
$$a_1, a, b, b_1 $$
$$a_{k-1}, \ldots, a_1, a, b, b_1, \ldots, b_{k - 1}.$$

And notice it has $2(k - 1) + 2 = 2k$ elements.

Comment: If there is an even number of elements do not average the middle two. Take the smaller one. In your case is would be 3, not 3.5

Comment: @user2612743 Okay, I will edit my response then.